# unexpected behavior ploting chart after a time interval with serialport data - c#

Tags: c#, charts, serial-port

i'm trying recieving data samplings trough serialport and plot a chart with this sampling vs time. the data is attatched to a resizable array and treated to correct some errors detactable by some marked bytes. i get recieve the data properly till 25 seconds. After this time, the data is unreadable and uncorrectable. i supected any configuration of buffersize of the serial port but any change does not solve this problem. and i don't find any configuration in the chart that could affect the behavior after certain point. my code to correct any error is limited and just works with litle bytes lost, not larger blocks. but what make confused is this constant lost axactly at 25s, that make me suspect of any colision and lost of larger blocks in serialport.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.BytesToRead != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            for (uint i0 = 0; i0 <= _In_Buffer.Length | serialPort1.BytesToRead != 0; i0++)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref _In_Buffer, (_In_Buffer.Length + 1));
                _In_Buffer[i0] = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
            }  
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

i'm new in c#, how you can see by the code. the baudrate is 115200 and redbuffersize 1048576. if someone can an idea what occurs to this behavior...

thx all

Comment: Hard to see how this could work at all, it just randomly scrambles the order of incoming data.  Remove try/catch, that just hides an inconvenient truth.  Use `Queue<byte>` to store the data.  Use a *lock* to make it thread-safe.  Always append new data to the end of the queue.

Comment: thank you, Hans! I'm new in c# and i don't know theses methods but i'll try. the try/catch is to solve a exception thrown by the a sudden desconection. i'm using a time to control the time of smapling and this routine disconnect the serial port during a reading. thank you